# How to make toMatchSnapshot() from Cypress work on Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, e2e-testing, snapshot, cypress

Currently I got one problem from implementing e2e test based on Cypress for Angular application.

I have posted my question here https://github.com/meinaart/cypress-plugin-snapshots/issues/38

I used [cypress-plugin-snapshots](https://github.com/meinaart/cypress-plugin-snapshots) to do snapshot test for my page. But the problem is that every time the test run they auto generated a new html and make the snapshot fail.

The reason is new snapshot have new attr _nghost-* and _ngcontent-* from Angular.

Do we have any solution for ignoring these two attributes on snapshot ?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/snapshot/issues/79#issuecomment-573619824